# How do I return 404 when tastypie is interfacing non-ORM sources?

Tags: python, rest, http-status-code-404, tastypie

I am using the facade-like pattern described here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html

```
def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    rv = MyObject(init=kwargs['pk'])
    audit_trail.message( ... )
    return rv
```

I can't return None, tosses an error.

Comment: Examining the source suggests to raise NotFound Exception (from tastypie.exception) with the body being: {"error_message": "Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please try again later."}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should raise an exception: **tastypie.exceptions.NotFound** (according to the code documentation).

I am working on tastypie for CouchDB and delved into the issue. In the tastypie.resources.Resource class you can find the method that you have to override:

```
def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Fetches an individual object on the resource.

    This needs to be implemented at the user level. If the object can not
    be found, this should raise a ``NotFound`` exception.

    ``ModelResource`` includes a full working version specific to Django's
    ``Models``.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

My example:

```
def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Fetches an individual object on the resource.

    This needs to be implemented at the user level. If the object can not
    be found, this should raise a ``NotFound`` exception.
    """
    id_ = kwargs['pk']
    ups = UpsDAO().get_ups(ups_id = id_)
    if ups is None:
        raise NotFound(
                "Couldn't find an instance of '%s' which matched id='%s'."%
                ("UpsResource", id_))
    return ups
```

One thing is strange for me. When I had a look at obj_get method in ModelResource class (the superclass of Resource class):

```
def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    A ORM-specific implementation of ``obj_get``.

    Takes optional ``kwargs``, which are used to narrow the query to find
    the instance.
    """
    try:
        base_object_list = self.get_object_list(request).filter(**kwargs)
        object_list = self.apply_authorization_limits(request, base_object_list)
        stringified_kwargs = ', '.join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])

        if len(object_list) <= 0:
            raise self._meta.object_class.DoesNotExist("Couldn't find an instance of '%s' which matched '%s'." % (self._meta.object_class.__name__, stringified_kwargs))
        elif len(object_list) > 1:
            raise MultipleObjectsReturned("More than '%s' matched '%s'." % (self._meta.object_class.__name__, stringified_kwargs))

        return object_list[0]
    except ValueError:
        raise NotFound("Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type).")
```

an exception: self._meta.object_class.DoesNotExist is raised when object is not found, which eventually becomes ObjectDoesNotExist exception - so it is not consensus inside the project.

Comment: And the exceptions source https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/exceptions.py

Answer (score 3):

I use ObjectDoesNotExist exeption from django.core.exceptions

```
   def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            info = Info.get(kwargs['pk'])
        except ResourceNotFound:
            raise ObjectDoesNotExist('Sorry, no results on that page.')
        return info
```